# Create Single Marco/Google Script and run to different spreadsheet by providing the URL or Key

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create single google script and run this to several raw files. The macro features does the of tagging circuit based on set formula, then once it is tag accordingly it will  automatically create sheet and segregate data base tagging. E.g. For extraction Sheet, For Validation

The first gscript that I did is the user should copy the raw on the templated fields. When done processing they need to create new spreadsheet and copy each sheet generate by the script. And clear and delete or redo everything from new everytime I need to run another raw. Which a bit hassle.

Therefore I would like to create dynamic macro that runs this script on several raw files one at a time. Then have templated forms that user will provide the URL before they run it.

The challenge is I cannot get the value on the raw file I can only get the value of B2 where the google script reside because it is my current active spreadsheet.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate(); 
var sURL  = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getValue(); // User provide the raw file URL
var rawFile= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sURL);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.getRange('A2').activate();
var gets  = ss.getActiveCell().getValue();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(gets);
```

Hope you can help. I really appreciate your help. Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by `I cannot get the value on the raw file`?

Comment: Hi Rafa, in sample script I'm initially trying to display the value of B3 from 2nd file (raw file) through openID then followed by an getactivepreadsheet function. I thought that if I open the another spreadsheet I can make it the active spreadsheet. Is it possible?

Comment: Moreover, the 1st file is like a form that ask the user to specify spreadsheetkey & sheet. Where in the 2nd file is the actual file specify by the user from the 1st file, i called it raw file since it needs to processes then it has several sheets each file as well.

The end state of the script is I want to create a front end (1st file) for the user which can dynamically request to process raw files (2nd file). Then script basically do the tagging and create sheet to segregated data based on tagging.  It will lessen manual tagging, and copying of sheets.

Comment: The `active` methods like `getActiveSpreadsheet()` or `getActiveSheet()` will ***only*** ever return the sheet that the script it bound to. You can't 'activate' another sheet in the same way. You can call all normal `Sheet` and `Range` methods on another sheet as long as you open it using `openById()`. Does this make sense? All calls to active sheets/spreadsheets will happen in the one the script is bound to. At the end, with `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(gets)` - is this meant to appear in the bound spreadsheet, or the externally opened one?